# Looping values in JsonObject

Tags: java, json, javax.json

I have given myself a task to loop values inside an [JsonObject](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm); for instance, I want my json to look like this:

```
{
        "cusEmail": "...",
        "totalQuantity": 11,
        "totalCost": 296.89,
        "phoneNumber": "844 463 9211",
        "address": "...",
        "closeShop": "...",
        "contact": "By email: and phone call::",
        "status": "...",
        "orderDate": "2017-15-12",
        "deliveryDate": "2017-12-18",
        "orderedItems": [
            {
                "name": "Blue Ribbon",
                "manufacture": "Blue Ribbon Brown Plus Low Gi Bread 700g",
                "price": 13.99,
                "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,..."
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Cheese",
                "manufacture": "Galbani Mozzarella Cheese 300g",
                "price": 49.99,
                "image": "data:image/octet-stream;base64,..."
                "count": 1
            }
        ]
}
```

And I have written this:

```
int cartSize = ShoppingCartController.getInstance().myProducts.size();

    String[] nameString = new String[cartSize];
    String[] imageString = new String[cartSize];
    Integer[] qauntityInteger = new Integer[cartSize];
    String[] manufactureString = new String[cartSize];
    Double[] priceDouble = new Double[cartSize];

    JsonObjectBuilder jsonObject = null;

    for ( int i = 0; i < cartSize; i++ ){

        Item myProducts = ShoppingCartController.getInstance().myProducts.get(i);

        nameString[i] = myProducts.getName();
        manufactureString[i] = myProducts.getManufacture();
        priceDouble[i] = myProducts.getPrice();
        imageString[i] = myProducts.getImage();
        qauntityInteger[i] = myProducts.getQuantity();

         jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                 .add("name", nameString[i])
                 .add("manufacture", manufactureString[i])
                 .add("price", priceDouble[i])
                 .add("image", imageString[i])
                 .add("count", qauntityInteger[i]);

    }



    JsonObject jsonParams = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("cusEmail", email)
                    .add("totalQuantity", quantity)
                    .add("totalCost", totalCost)
                    .add("phoneNumber", phoneNumber)
                    .add("address", address)
                    .add("closeShop", closeShop)
                    .add("contact", contact)
                    .add("status", "ordered")
                    .add("orderDate", dateFormat.format(orderDate))
                    .add("deliveryDate", delDate)
                    .add("orderedItems", Json.createArrayBuilder()
                            .add(jsonObject))
            .build();
```

Of course jsonObject will return the last object of the loop, which will then be added *alone*.

How will I loop and add all objects into my arrayBuilder?

Comment: create array builder before loop, fill arraybuilder inside loop and set orderedItems after ?

Comment: created 1 array and then append the overedItems to each json object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the example in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html), you can have a [JsonArrayBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.html), to which you can add your JsonObjects, like:

```
JsonArrayBuilder arrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
arrayBuilder.add(jsonObject);
```

Then, add the array to the final JsonObject, like:

```
JsonObject jsonParams = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("cusEmail", email)
                    ...
                    .add("orderedItems", arrayBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject cart = new JSONObject();
        cart.put("cusEmail", email);
        cart.put("totalQuantity", quantity);
        cart.put("totalCost", totalCost);
        cart.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        cart.put("address", address);
        cart.put("closeShop", closeShop);
        cart.put("contact", contact);
        cart.put("status", "ordered");
        cart.put("orderDate", dateFormat.format(orderDate));
        cart.put("deliveryDate", delDate);

        JSONArray objects = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("name", nameString[i]);
            obj.put("manufacture", manufactureString[i]);
            obj.put("price", priceDouble[i]);
            obj.put("image", imageString[i]);
            obj.put("count", qauntityInteger[i]);

            objects.add(obj);
        }
        cart.put("orderedItems", objects);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the array builder first, add all json objects, and then build the array and add it to the root object:

```
JsonArrayBuilder array = Json.createArrayBuilder();

for ( int i = 0; i < cartSize; i++ ){
    ...

     array.add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("name", nameString[i])
             .add("manufacture", manufactureString[i])
             .add("price", priceDouble[i])
             .add("image", imageString[i])
             .add("count", qauntityInteger[i]));

}

JsonObject jsonParams = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("cusEmail", email)
                .add("totalQuantity", quantity)
                .add("totalCost", totalCost)
                .add("phoneNumber", phoneNumber)
                .add("address", address)
                .add("closeShop", closeShop)
                .add("contact", contact)
                .add("status", "ordered")
                .add("orderDate", dateFormat.format(orderDate))
                .add("deliveryDate", delDate)
                .add("orderedItems", array.build())
        .build();
```